# "this instanceof Animal" と "this === instanceof Animal" の差を教えてください

Tags: javascript

いつもお世話になっています。
下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示を願います。

---

### 【質問の主旨】

[GitHub](https://github.com/echizenyayota/ch6/blob/developer/scripts/es5_class3.js)にUPしたコードではAnimalクラス内で条件文を使用しています。そのうち

```
if (!(this instanceof Animal)) {
    return new Animal(name);
}
```

上記のコードを使ってコンソール画面を表示させると、以下の結果が表示されます。

```
トクジロウ
Animal: トクジロウ
```

```
if (!(this === instanceof Animal)) {
    return new Animal(name);
}
```

一方、上記のコードを用いると下記のエラーが表示されます。

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token instanceof
```

両者の間において結果に差が出るのはなぜでしょうか？

### 【質問の補足】

#### 1.

公式ドキュメントで[instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)の用例を確認すると、

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}

var auto = new Car('Honda', 'Accord', 1998);
console.log(auto instanceof Car);
```

という感じでinstanceof演算子の前に、オブジェクトを記述するという用例があります。ただし今回の質問で使っている`this`については特別に何かを定義している感じがしません。

#### 2.

個人的な予測ですが今回の質問で使われている`this`は、グローバルオブジェクトを表す特殊なキーワードではないかと推測しています。もしthisがグローバルオブジェクトであるならば、`this === instanceof Animal`としても条件式として文法的に正しい表現をしていると思います。

---

以上、ご確認よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`instanceof`は二項演算子なので、文法上の扱いは`*`などと同じです。よって`hoge === * 3`がSyntaxErrorになるのと同じ理由で、`this === instanceof Animal`もSyntaxErrorとなります。

参考: https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: apple502j さん。コメントありがとうございます。`instanceof` が二項演算子であることをはじめて分かりました。文法上の扱いだけであれば`this instanceof Animal` は `2 * 3` と同じであると認識しておきます。